# Using SnapshotStateList with LazyColumn: adding new items causes IllegalArgumentException key was already used

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a basic `SnapshotStateList` that I add and remove items from. It's stored in a `MutableStateFlow` along with the rest of the UI state for this screen, and exposed as a StateFlow to the composables, on my ViewModel, because I sometimes want to be able to swap the entire list out for a completely different one, but that will only happen when the rest of the UI state needs to be swapped out as well. Here's what that looks like (in miniature):

```kotlin
date class SomeUiState(
    val channelId: String? = null
    // ... other UI state ...
    val messages: SnapshotStateList<Message> = mutableStateListOf()
)

@HiltViewModel
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    // Messages repository exposes messages for each channel as MutableStateFlows, and handles adding, removing, and updating messages as necessary inside itself.
    private val messagesRepository: MessagesRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ServerChannelUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<ServerChannelUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    // ...

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            currentChannelStateFlow.collectLatest { channelId: String? ->
                _uiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        channelId = channelId,
                        messages = messagesRepository.getMessagesForChannel(channelId)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `SnapshotStateList` is then consumed by a `LazyColumn`, like so:

```kotlin
val uiState by channelViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(
        uiState.messages,
        key = { _, it -> "${it.messageId}${it.timestamp}" },
    ) { index, message ->
        Message(message)
    }
}
```

About 90% of the time, this works fine, even across many adds, deletes, adds again, updates, etc. But 10% of the time, adding a new message triggers an `IllegalArgumentException` "key is already being used." I assumed this was because the server was reusing message IDs from previously deleted messages for new messages, so I made the message timestamp part of the key, since for a new message to reuse the ID of an older deleted message, it must obviously be created after the deleted message, just by its very nature. I even made the timestamp include the millisecond the message was created, so collisions would be extremely difficult. This changed nothing. I kept getting the exception. So I changed tack, and had my program log *every, single, one* of the message IDs and timestamps it ever put in its messages list. By doing this, when adding a new message produced the "key was already used" error, I was able to confirm that the key LazyColumn was claiming had already been used... had in fact *not* already been used, since I had a list of all previously used keys to check it against.

So LazyColumn is very clearly marking brand new, unique keys as duplicates of themselves when they're added into the list. What is causing this? Is there any way around this? I don't want to have to switch to `SharedFlow<List<>>` or something because that would mean a complete rerender of LazyColumn every time any change is made, which would be catastrophic for the performance of an often-used messaging app.

Comment: I'd bet a big money on the possibility that you actually have the same item multiple times in the list :) "the server was reusing message IDs" - nobody sane would have done this.. "This changed nothing" - yeah, another pointer that there is the very same message twice in your list (same id, same timestamp). The code you posted looks fine, show us how the repository looks like.

Comment: @JanBína I suppose it's possible, but recall I had it print out every single message ID and timestamp that was ever added to the list, and checked the supposedly duplicate key from the error message against that list and found no match. And I've heard of mutableStateList doing weird things with LazyColumn. But in any case you're right, that's a possibility, here's the repo (fair warning its a bit big): https://github.com/alexispurslane/bloc/tree/develop

Comment: I went through the code a bit and one thing that struck me is that inside of `RevoltWebSocketModule.eventFlow.collect`, you are checking `existingMessageIds` first before inserting the message, but inside `integrateMessages` you are not - and you don't even add the messages inserted there to the `existingMessageIds` - couldn't this be the problem?

Comment: I do add it: https://github.com/alexispurslane/bloc/blob/d59ce7f6107b70107acebb8d2464272c18774061/app/src/main/java/io/github/alexispurslane/bloc/data/RevoltMessagesRepository.kt#L65 and  https://github.com/alexispurslane/bloc/blob/d59ce7f6107b70107acebb8d2464272c18774061/app/src/main/java/io/github/alexispurslane/bloc/data/RevoltMessagesRepository.kt#L475; but In a newer version of the code I've ripped out all of the existing message ID stuff because it doesn't seem to do anything anyway.